# https URL redirecting to external site

Tags: url, redirect, ssl, https

Hi I have a website that I will be developing in the future.

Upon looking at the current website I noticed something weird that I have never seen before and also Google'd and found nothing.

If you go to: http://www.smartrainer.com.au you get the normal site

But, if you go to: https://www.smartrainer.com.au you get redirected to another website and are also given an SSL warning beforehand (in Chrome)

The site is hosted on a UNIX / PHP server and the .htaccess file currently has nothing that would suggest that it's redirecting to this other website.

Any help or insight would be appreciated with this, because I've never heard of this or seen this before.. The client also has no idea why it would be directing to that company that we've never heard of

Thanks!

Comment: This would be better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a shared hosting server.

In plain HTTP, the server can know which host the client is requesting using the `Host` header in the request (this is based on the URL). Apache Httpd supports this with what it calls [Name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

The HTTPS configuration is separate from the HTTP configuration in Apache Httpd (and presumably a number of other servers). Having virtual hosts (typically on a shared host) for the HTTP configuration doesn't mean that the same configuration is replicated for HTTPS.

HTTPS presents another problem: choosing which certificate to send before being able to see the `Host` header. Indeed, the server needs to send the client a certificate with the correct name during the SSL/TLS handshake, which happens before any HTTP traffic is sent (so before the `Host` header can be read). To overcome this problem, some hosts will set up a certificate valid for multiple host names (typically multiple Subject Alternative Names, or sometimes wilcards), others will use Server Name Indication (which isn't supported by all clients).

To get your server to host your site for HTTPS, you'd need:

- To make sure the certificate it serves is valid for your host name (otherwise, there will be a warning message).
- That the virtual hosts (or equivalent) it serves are configured for your host too.

In your case it seems that (a) your server is serving a single certificate that is not valid for your host and (b) your host isn't configured for HTTPS anyway, since you're falling back to what's probably the default host.

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed response. You're correct it is a shared host. I'll investigate with my provider and make sure to mark your answer as correct if this is the case.

Also, I should mention that the site will not need a HTTPS connection and therefore we will not set one up - I assume this just means that I need to check with my provider and they should be able to fix the problem?

Comment: @CharlesEnglish, if your site doesn't need an HTTPS connection, but if other sites using the same IP address as yours (on the same host) do and there's an HTTPS service listening to incoming connections, attempts to connect to your site using with HTTPS will inevitably be initially served by what's listening there, with whichever certificate is configured on that service, so users attempting connections with HTTPS will get a similar error. (There might be an option to return something like "no such host" completely, for clients using SNI.)

Answer (score -1):

You may solve this issue by redirecting HTTPS URL to HTTP URL from your .htaccess. This error might because of shared hosting. If you cannot solve this issue from your .htaccess than you may also contact your hosting provider on this issue.

Comment: Redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP won't really help, since it's too late to prevent the certificate warning.

Comment: @bruno have you tried it? if it is not working, you must contact your hosting providers.

Comment: @PeggyP, it's not a matter of trying it. If the certificate is invalid for a certain host, the SSL/TLS connection won't be established (unless the users accepts the invalid cert, which they shouldn't), therefore the HTTP request on top of the SSL/TLS connection won't happen, therefore the HTTP redirection, which comes from an HTTP response to this initial request will not happen. Redirections from HTTPS to HTTP are completely pointless when the cert is invalid. This has nothing to do with hosting providers.

Comment: @Bruno i understand your point but in this case, they did not install any SSL on their server which map their Domain. I think this is happening only because of shared hosting !!

Comment: @PeggyP, of course this is happening because of shared hosting, because a server for a different host name is listening at that IP address on port 443. However, the suggestion this may be fixed with `.htaccess` settings (or any other form of HTTPS->HTTP redirection) is completely misleading.